# Javascript - How to store unknown count 2d arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have unknown count of 2d arrays (they can be generated in real time)

```
array1[][], array2[][][], array3[][], ... arrayN[][]
```

How I can store this arrays, so that I can then work with them, use?

Example: array store[10] which store this 2d arrays:

```
store[1] = array1[][]
store[2] = array2[][]
..
store[10] = array10[][]
```

Comment: `I hope you got what I meant` NO.

Comment: add i want to work with this 2d arrays (set, get)

Comment: @void I do not know how to number and access unknown count of 2d arrays

Comment: `array1[][], array2[][][], array3[][], ... arrayN[][]` this does not represent anything in JS. Are these 2D arrays stored in a variable? Can you describe your problem and your code more clearly?

Comment: Please share your inputs, your current code, your current result, and your expected result.

Comment: I think he's trying to clone a 2D array to another array, making a 3D array.

Comment: @void yes, this is 2d arrays. I am beginner in JS.

Comment: @Xufox, i havent code yet... I think create some function Create2DArray() which will return 2d array! But i dont know how i will store this 2d arrays if i will call this function e.g. by clicking some button.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has jagged arrays only, so arrays stored in arrays. Here arrays `a`, `b` and `c` are stored in `d` to form a 2D construct, and then you could store `d` into an element of some other array and get a 3rd layer (or dimension if you like).

```js
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[7,8,9]
d=[a,b,c]
console.log("d:",d);
console.log("d[0][0]:",d[0][0]);
console.log("d[1][0]:",d[1][0]);

e=[];
e.push(5);
e.push("Hello");
e[5]=10;
console.log("e:",e);
console.log("e[100]:",e[100]);
```

For collecting an unknown amount of items, see the story with `e`. You can use the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method of arrays, which just appends an element dynamically. An on top of that arrays are both sparse and unbounded, you can set/get previously non-existent elements any time.

One side remark: the `someArray[x][y]` thing is important, you can not write it as `someArray[x,y]`, because JavaScript does not have such syntax, but it has `,` ([comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)), which means that `x,y` is an expression which evaluates to `y` (its last operand). So `someArray[x,y]` is actually `someArray[y]`, with a single dimension.

Comment: I will store `d` arrays in other array. Thanks for response.